# Keep Buttons at bottom of layout visible when list is long

Tags: android, layout, button

I have a layout that is three linear layouts.  The top has some icons and the middle has a tabhost.  Each tabhost has a list inside it.  The bottom linearlayout has two buttons that should stay at the bottom on the screen at all times.  The problem is when a list in the tabhost gets too long, it displays over the buttons.  I tried to find some way to get the buttons to bedisplayed over the list but have failed so far.  Any help would be appreciated. :-)  Thanks!

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TabHost 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="395dp"
            android:background="#000000">
            <TabWidget 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />
            <FrameLayout 
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" 
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:gravity="fill"
android:layout_margin="0dp" 
android:padding="0dp" 
>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnGroup" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Ptt" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Menu" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally put my `LinearLayout`s inside of a `ScrollView` to solve this situation. (The buttons stay outside) It allows your buttons to stay in the correct location at all times and the user scroll the rest of the view.

[ScrollView Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I do have the buttons at the bottom at all times now!  However, I am feeling rather stupid as now the scroll view is not big enough and leaves lots of empty space before the buttons.  I tried setting minHeight and also trying fillViewPort but niether seems to be working.  ANy ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I made a silyl mistake.  I thought you could only do "fill_parent" or "wrap_content" for height but have realized I can put numbers in there.  Thanks for your help Chris! :-)

Comment: Instead of using the numbers I would set the weight of the scroll view to 2 so that it will occupy any unfilled space. Setting numbers is bad practice when dealing with multiple screen sizes in most cases.

Comment: I gave that a shot because I dont like using numbers either. However when I set weight it still does fill the rest of the screen.
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="2">

Comment: Sorry I meant to say does not

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new layout in a code block please.